# If statement throws error instead of moving to next line

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to detect a popup that doesn't always occur using an If statement where if the element is found click the no thanks option else next function

```py
import time
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import pyautogui
import re
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

serv = Service(r"C:\Users\Batman\Desktop\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv)
driver.get("https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/0-UG15dVNvUU9sTVVLa2ovUFAvZmh4QT090/overview")
driver.maximize_window


def FeedBack():
#popup asking for feedback
    if driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,("noButton.buttons")):
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "noButton.buttons").click()
    else:
        DriversAndDownloads()
FeedBack()
```

The Full code

```py
import time
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import pyautogui
import re
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


serv = Service(r"C:\Users\Batman\Desktop\Batman\Pycharm\DellUpdate - selenium\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv)
driver.get("https://www.dell.com/support")
driver.maximize_window()



def Step1():
    SearchBar = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "entry-main-input-home").send_keys("3Q84KQ2")
    SearchBarClick = driver.find_element(By.ID,"txtSearchEs").click()
Step1()


def Popup():
#30 second popup
    if driver.find_element(By.ID, "sec-overlay"):
        time.sleep(30.5)
        SearchBarClick = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtSearchEs").click()
    else: FeedBack()
Popup()


def FeedBack():
#popup asking for feedback
    if driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,("noButton.buttons")):
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "noButton.buttons").click()
    else:
        DriversAndDownloads()
FeedBack()

def DriversAndDownloads():
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "drivers").click()
DriversAndDownloads()


def FindDrivers():
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "btn.collapse-toggle.table-collapse-toggle.collapsed").click()
FindDrivers()
```

The difference between the two above codes is the first will take you to where the popup "should" randomly comes up. (I tested a few times and it didn't seem to popup once from the link directly to that page) which was a great way to play with the IF statement

the Second code is the full code (minus the function that gets the Dell serial number, I've provided a working serial to test with).

Final note- I did find out that I can just add a feature to refresh the page(f5) and it'll skip the popup every time upon reloading. The only problem with this is it doesn't help me figure out the code for what I assume is written correctly based on my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.find_element` will throw exception if no element found.
You should use `driver.find_elements` instead.
It will return a list. In case of element existence it will return a non-empty list enterpreted by Python as True. Otherwise it will return an empty list interpreted by Python as Boolean False.
So, instead of

```py
if driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,("noButton.buttons")):
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "noButton.buttons").click()
else:
    DriversAndDownloads()
```

Try using

```py
if driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,("noButton.buttons")):
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "noButton.buttons").click()
else:
    DriversAndDownloads()
```

Comment: Okay so it looks like  my else statement is messing up because DriversAndDownlaods() is called before it's written. (*Human thinking* it's supposed to move to that next *.py thinking* it doesn't exist yet.   Any suggestions on resolving that?

Comment: I really have ho idea what is the `DriversAndDownloads` method, where is it defined etc. You did not mention that in your code. It even sound like a *new*, separate question..

Comment: In the 2nd set of code (full) it shows the DriversAndDownloads() function. it's the one after FeedBack()

Comment: OK, what prevents you from putting the definition of that method before the `if-else` block we are dealing with?

Comment: I can only assume "the forest that is blocking my view of the trees". I was able to move that above and the code run I'm checking now to see if it is actually clicking no when the pop up

Comment: OK, let me know if now your problem resolved or there are still not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247482/discussion-between-navi-and-prophet).

Answer (score 0):

`if driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,("noButton.buttons"))` won't work in case element not found since it doesn't return boolean `True`/`False` but `WebElement` instance or `NoSuchElementException`. You need either do

```
if driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,("noButton.buttons")):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

or

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,("noButton.buttons"))
    # do something
except NoSuchElementException:
    # do something else
```

Comment: So far I think the Try/except is going to be the best option for this because of the fact my If/else is trying to call a function that hasn't been defined until 3 lines later. I personally don't know of a python way to call it before it's made.

Comment: @navi so why not to define functions in correct order?

Comment: it is. based on how the website runs it may have a popup that comes up for feedback (Feedback() is supposed to click no thanks if the pop up is there) if not it should move to the next function which would be DriversAndDownloads(This is what the screen would be showing if the popup didn't occur.)  
I think what happened on that is I was thinking in human instead of python. the overall action is still preferred (if the search for the popup == true run code to"close popup" else do next function)

Comment: @navi if you call `DriversAndDownloads` in `FeedBack ` then you need to define `DriversAndDownloads` before `FeedBack`. But actually looking at your code I don't even understand why you use those functions :) You can simply write those lines without any functions - you just don't need them!

Comment: it was mostly to help me separate visibly each action that's happening in the code. It's been suggested I reach out for debugging; I got DriversAndDownloads to run when the popup doesn't occur but FeedBack() is still having issues clicking the no button.

Comment: @navi `FeedBack()` might not work since 1. You pass *tupple* as locator instead of *string*. 2. Even if to pass *string* I'm not sure that there is a `"noButton.buttons"` HTML tag. Probably you mean `By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".noButton.buttons"` or something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247484/discussion-between-navi-and-curious-koala).